# How do I deal with serialization unsetting object members?

Tags: 8

Let's say I have a plugin that uses an injected service to get some object. The object is expensive but can't be serialized, so I can only store it as long as my plugin instance lives.

To keep it away from `DependencySerializationTrait`, I declare it private.

```
class MyPlugin extends SomePluginBase implements ContainerFactoryPluginInterface {

  /**
   * @var \Drupal\module\ServiceInterface
   */
  protected $service;

  /**
   * @var \Drupal\module\SomeUnserializableThing
   */
  private $data;

  /**
   * Constructor
   *
   * @param \Drupal\module\ServiceInterface $service
   */
  public __construct(ServiceInterface $service) {
    $this->service = $service;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new static($container->get('my_module.service'));
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public getData() {
    if (!$this->data) {
      $this->data = $this->service->loadData();
    }
    return $this->data;
  }

}
```

Unfortunately, after serializing and unserializing the instance doesn't have *any* reference to the member - not even NULL. What happens in ::getData is that the `!$this->data` check causes an E_NOTICE error *even though that variable is explicitly defined in the class*.

Are we back to the dark age of `isset()` and `empty()` here, or do I need to implement __wakeup() for all my classes to explicitly initialize their private members to NULL? Both seem unpalatable...

Comment: That sounds...weird, and possibly buggy. What version of PHP are you using? Do you get the same result if you initialise the property in its definition? (`private $data = NULL;`) Out of interest why are you shying away from the trait to solve this?

Comment: The trait works on services from the container - in this case, it correctly unsets the `$service` variable and notes down `_serviceIds = ['service' => 'my_module.service']`. However, it leaves all other `protected` variables alone - and if `$data` is something that can't be serialized (for whatever reason), I have to make it `private` to let it avoid serialization.

Answer (score 0):

__sleep() works by returning properties that need to be serialized. A private property is invisible, won't show up in $vars and therefore is also not serialized and just silently dropped.

Either don't use private (it only serialized *services*, I assume data is not a service), or override __sleep(), call the parent and then add data to the list of properties to be serialized.